# Cannot redeclare function (even after die();)

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
    if (ismobile()) {
        // Include mobile version of this page
        require_once("mobile_signup.php");

        // Die so it will not include desktop version below mobile version
        die();
    }
    function this_is_a_function() {
        // Some code here
    }

   // Desktop version of code here
```

mobile_signup.php also has the function called "this_is_a_function()" declared in it. How can I properly do this? I realize there is a "function_exists('this_is_a_function')", but there is MANY functions in both of these codes, so it would be impractical to do this for all functions on both pages.

This site was pre-built and I am attempting to turn it into a mobile-friendly site. So it would not be an easy task to rewrite the whole script.

Comment: why are you using die() exactly?

Comment: You could use [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php)

Comment: Just change the name of the function. `die()` will not garbage functions.

Comment: I am using die so it will show the mobile page instead. The desktop page is at the bottom of the shown code

Comment: There is no way the second function could be reached - php does not pre-compile the scripts or parse through - it's essentially executed line-by-line. If ismobile() is true, then the external file's included and then die() is executed. PHP would never read the redeclaration.

Comment: That is what I would have thought.. But it is not working that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to immediately `die()` after including your mobile version file in the beginning of a page and still expect it to run fine, that means your mobile file can run standalone on its own; hence a redirect is a better option here.

```
header("Location: mobile_signup.php");
```

`die()` does stop execution but it does not mean that if you use it somewhere then all the code below it becomes useless, it will still be parsed by PHP

Answer (score 1):

Your question was a bit confusing however I am assuming you want different functions based on if they are on mobile or not.

To do this just require a page with mobile function if they are on mobile, and require a separate page if they are not on mobile and keep functions that are used on both mobile and other on the main page. This way it won't hit any problems with functions being defined twice.

If you need this to work because the pages are **not** related to each other, then just call the functions something different is the simplest answer.

Once again I am not sure which one of the above is your problem because your question was not detailed enough as to what each page did, what the current page did, etc.

Answer (score 1):

all function are registered in php system during parsing, so if your duplication functions are inside dynamic and conditional includes that can make sure that no duplicate funciton will come then it will be ok, but if they are in same script or in one execution process, then it will gives your error, remember its parse time error,

remember php first parse script then execute it, so function are declared first, then script excuted so `die()` executed after parsing,

in wordpress like environment where are functions are decalred in global namespace its best pratice to use this coding style

```
if (!function_exists('HelloFunc'))
     function HelloFunc(){
         // do
     }
```

or in your current code i would suggest you to use this pattern

```
if (ismobile()) {
    // Include mobile version of this page
    require_once("mobile_signup.php");
} else {
    // Include mobile version of this page
    require_once("desktop_signup.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

die() will halt the running script . It will not stop the php parser from parsing the code after the line where die() is encountered.
when you include the file... the parser will compile it completely after including the code and die() has nothing to do here ...

You have to check whether function is already exists or not.. or use different function names